# freebase filter by multiple types

Tags: api, freebase

Is it possible to filter query by multiple types in freebase API?

I need to search for keyword within two or three freebase types, but it seems that freebase API doesn't allow this option. In that case probably the only solution is to send two or three separate requests for filtered types?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give a more specific example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can filter by multiple types using the search API or the MQL read API.

For the search API that looks [like this](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=london&filter=%28any%20type:/music/musical_group%20type:/people/person%20type:/location/citytown%29):

```
filter=(any type:/music/musical_group type:/people/person type:/location/citytown)
```

This filter tells it to constrain the results to match one of the 3 types.

In the MQL Read API you can filter by multiple types [like this](http://www.freebase.com/api/service/mqlread?query=%7B%20%22query%22%3a%20%5B%7B%20%22id%22%3a%20null,%20%22name%22%3a%20null,%20%22type%22%3a%20%5B%5D,%20%22name~=%22%3a%20%22London%22,%20%22type%7C=%22%3a%20%5B%20%22/people/person%22,%20%22/location/citytown%22,%20%22/music/musical_group%22%20%5D%20%7D%5D%20%7D):

```
[{
  "id":            null,
  "name":          null,
  "type": [],
  "name~=": "London",
  "type|=": [
    "/people/person",
    "/location/citytown",
    "/music/musical_group"
  ]
}​]​
```